# TextViews with dividers in between them

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I am trying to recrate following layout in android studio:

[image: Preview image]

Because i am preety new at android stuff, i first tryed with LinearLayout, and figured thath this probably wont be possible with it. Now i am trying with RelativeLayout i already created this block with color:

```
        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:background="@color/red_top">
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Now i want to ask how can i divide it like it is shown at the image 1 bar at top and 2 at the bottom in the same layout, and how can i put same borders?

Comment: He said he specifically needs them in the same Layout; the TableLayout that bakriOnFire suggested is also great.

Comment: Its in the same parent layout(Linear), and inside it,the layout nesting is done.

Comment: Ah, yes you are right.  My apologies.

Comment: its all right...!!! no need to apologise.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do this by using the following xml code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/custom_toast_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#CD96CD"
        android:text="TEXT" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#CD96CD"
            android:text="TEXT" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#CD96CD"
            android:text="TEXT" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How can i add another text view with the bottom line so i will have like 
Text1 Text2 | Text3 Text4 
If i try to add just another textview it expand the right over the screen.

Comment: At the bottom line now i have 2 text views. How can i add 2 more thath i will have like on the left side: Wins: 0 (2 text views), on the right Lost: 0 (2 text views)?

Comment: see either you can set text through settext like textview.settext("Wins: "+ no.of wins) ,this will save an additional textview else you can do it by the code I'm posting below.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/FirstLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/FirstTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TEXT_ONE" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/SecondLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/FirstLinearLayout"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/SecondTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TEXT_TWO" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ThirdTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TEXT_Three" />
</LinearLayout>
```

First you will need a container to hold all of your components inside; in my example the container I am talking about is the `RelativeLayout`.  Relative Layouts allow their children to be placed in their position using the corresponding IDs.  Take a look at how I positioned the other two `LinearLayout`s using `android:layout_below="@+id/FirstLinearLayout"`.

If you really insist on having them in the same Layout, use a relative layout and position the `TextView`s as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/FirstTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TEXT_ONE" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/SecondTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/FirstTextView"
        android:text="TEXT_TWO" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ThirdTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/FirstTextView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/SecondTextView"
        android:text="TEXT_Three" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 1):

A `TableLayout` is the best option, to accomplish your need.

```
<TableLayout>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:text="Text" />

    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text" />

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Note the `layout_span` attribute used in the first `TextView` to span tow columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to add additional TextViews

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#CD96CD"
    android:text="TEXT" />

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#000000" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#CD96CD"
        android:text="TEXT" />
     <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#000000" />
     <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#CD96CD"
        android:text="TEXT" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#CD96CD"
        android:text="TEXT" />
     <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#000000" />
     <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#CD96CD"
        android:text="TEXT" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this view; draw you a seperator between your textviews

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#000000" />
```