# [Android]: How to style divider in listSeparatorTextView?

Tags: android, textview, android-styles, list-separator

I'm looking for a way to change the color of the line under this textview, which is called the divider. As you can see in the code below, I changed the style to listSeparatorTextViewStyle. I know I have to add some extra code in the styles.xml file in the 'values folder' but I'm only able to change the backgroundcolor or the textcolor... 
Is there anyone with a solution on how to change the dividercolor ???

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAddress"
        style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/etDescription"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/etDescription"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etDescription"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="Address"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#ff0f67b0"/>
```

I like to change the color of the divider in the red box.

[image: printscreen android]

Comment: See this [question:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12171209/change-the-line-color-used-in-listseparatortextviewstyle)

Comment: Or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18444913/textviews-with-dividers-in-between-them)

Comment: @Clyde: I tried them, first one said that it doesn't know Widget.TextView.ListSeparator as a parent

Comment: @Clyde: and the second one is not using the listSeparaterorTextView

Answer (score 0):

There is certainly a best solution but it's working for me :

1) Set the background of the TextView to white or to the background of your activity (the divider will not be shown)

2) Just under the TextView set an ImageView of a rectangle (dimensions will be : 5px for height and 1000px for witdh and set to this ImageView marginLeft and marginRight to 5dp for example.

3) Don't forget to adapt your rectangle for tablet !